# UPC / SKU Database

Tags: database, download, skus

Do any of you know where I can find a good UPC database to be downloaded?
or even a online UPC lookup, I've tried UPCDatabase.com and personally, I didn't like it that much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

did you already check [searchupc.com](http://www.searchupc.com/api/)?